# creating a function or sproc to replace real data with pseudo random data

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to scrub data out of tables that can be classified as [PHI](http://searchhealthit.techtarget.com/definition/personal-health-information).

Let's say the real data looks like this:

```
+-------------------+-----------+------+
|       Name        | Condition | Code |
+-------------------+-----------+------+
| Alex              | A         |   12 |
| Laura             | BB        |   32 |
| Bob               | AAA       |   55 |
| Gary              | C         |   32 |
+-------------------+-----------+------+
```

I will need to replace my **Name** column with the following fake names:

Names_Reference_Table:

```
+-------------+----+
|    Name     | ID |
+-------------+----+
| JOHN        |  1 |
| ROBERT      |  2 |
| MICHAEL     |  3 |
| WILLIAM     |  4 |
| DAVID       |  5 |
| RICHARD     |  6 |
| CHARLES     |  7 |
| JOSEPH      |  8 |
| THOMAS      |  9 |
| CHRISTOPHER | 10 |
| DANIEL      | 11 |
| PAUL        | 12 |
| MARK        | 13 |
| DONALD      | 14 |
| GEORGE      | 15 |
+-------------+----+
```

Though I have 10,000,000 real data records, I have only 10,000 fake data records. I am assuming that every fake name will be repeated 1000 times when replacing the real data.

The trick here is that this needs to be **recreatable**. After googling for hours, I did find some good sources, and I've created some kind of implementation that is deterministic, assuming that the seed does not change:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND(@seed * LOG([p].[patientid]) * 1000) * ( @count_names - 1 ) + 1)
```

As you can see from above, when you pass the same seed to RAND(), it will return the same value. However, this implementation is brittle.

**Has anyone guidance on how to generate this deterministic behavior?**

Comment: I don't follow your question.  What do you mean by "brittle"?  What is `patientid`?

Comment: if my table of fake names contains 10m records, i will not be able to cover 100% of the names using only rand(@seed) ... i need to write this annoying expression log(patient id) * some other big constant, but making sure it's not too big because then i'll get an overflow exception, patientid is an int ... im using it in order that i would be able to recreate this at a future date, as the patientid will remain the same if that makes any sense

Comment: @GordonLinoff does that provide more clarify or not really? innomatics answer below is almost hitting the nail on the head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the checksum or some other hashing function e.g.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Names_Reference_Table
WHERE ID = ABS(CHECKSUM('John')) % 10000
```

Assuming you have 10,000 fake names

Comment: thank you very much, the assumption is that i have 10m real names but only 10k fake names

Comment: thanks! can we throw in the getdate() function somehow so that if i wanted to generate the same data tomorrow, it would be different because it would be a function of the date? something like WHERE ID = ABS(CHECKSUM('John') + cast(getdate() as int)) % 10000  ??????

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Does the replacement name need to be stable with respect to the `patientid` rather than the `name`?  For example, if a patient's name changes when they enter witness protection would you want the replacement name to remain unchanged because it is based on the original id, not name?

Comment: what do you say @innomatics?

Comment: You can certainly use getdate or any kind of random salt to make it more difficult to reverse engineer the true names.  As Habo suggested you could also just take (and optionally hash) the patient_id and and mod that - although I presume you'll need to do something similar with last names as well, which precludes using the ID.  BTW last names are typically more identifying so you definitely should be masking them as well.  Don't forget to mark your chosen (if any) answer as accepted when your happy!

Comment: the thing that complicates this is that i need to be able to go back in time if the data changes and be able to recreate the data that was used for the masking process. the real data changes daily, so i would need to be able to show what the real data was transformed TO a few days ago. this is why i cannot use that ranking function because the real data set can grow and shrink in size, changing the rankings

Comment: is it possible to go backwards? lets say we get a result of 1234 for that checksum expression ... can we go backwards to get the refid that it is associated with?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly actual names are more than dummy names. So you want to replace the actual names with dummy names by repeating dummy names by 1000 against the real name. This can be achieved by using Ntile function as follows -

```
declare @i int = (select max(id) from reference_table)
select b.name,a.condition,a.code from
(
select name,condition,code, Ntile(@i) over (order by code) as RefId
from actualTable
) as a
Left join Refrence_table as b
on b.id = a.refid
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Sam the main challenge is creating the reference table

Comment: From your above explanation I could understand that Your reference table has 10,000 names and your actual names are 10,000,000. ?

Comment: Correct. How do you associate a specific patient ID with a reference table name?

Comment: that is with help of function name ntile(). Just run my above code and let me know if you are getting the desired output

Comment: not really. let's say i add more records to the real names, if i re-run your algorithm then it will give me different results unfortunately, but this is a great post

Comment: I have edited the above code. It is dynamic now try again  and let me know. I am sure this thing works as I have used the same in my work environment.